# Eclipse freezes when trying to save .dslr file in Drools

Tags: eclipse, drools, dsl

I am new to drools and I'm trying to create rules with DSL , I was able to create the DSL file and write few rules then I created the .dslr file I don't know why every time I try to save it , the whole eclipse freezes and I'm unable to relaunch it again until I go to the workspace and delete the .dslr file . 
Could you please tell me what's the problem and how I can fix it ?
Thank you

PS : the eclipse freezes when the code contains System.out.println , does anyone know how to make simple display with DSL ?

Comment: Hi @balance, welcome! Could you please post your rules code on your question? :)

Comment: thank you , I tried but I'm not able to post images because I'm new to the website , 
do you think it's related to the code ? I just try to save the file and  Eclipse freezes completely

Comment: in the .dslr file :
package mypackage 
expander file.dsl

rule " myrule" 
when 
EtatClimat pleuviometrie has value {value}
then 
Log "{message}"
end

that's it , and the when and then parts are already written as they are in the .dsl file

Comment: What'S the Drools version? - Not sure what the plugin tries to do with a dslr, but try and omit the `expander file.dsl`.

Comment: I'm working with Drools 5.4.0 , the .dslr file uses the .dsl file to generate .drl rules .. that's what I read from the Drools documentation